# Placing vertical line behind other plots in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, charts, line

I am trying add a vertical line using Matplotlib but I want it to be behind my other plot lines. Currently it overlaps my other lines. Is there a simple way to do this?

```
plt.axvline(x=date, linestyle=':', color='lightgray')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should use the parameter `zorder`

```
plt.axvline(x=date, linestyle=':', color='lightgray', zorder=0)
```

your other lines need an higher `zorder` values